# Print client local IP on browser

Tags: java, javascript, applet, network-programming

everyone! I'm currently struggling to print the client's IP address in my page. I've been researching about it and it seems that JavaScript isn't an option. Since my webpage is developed on Rails i thought about coding in ruby but I think that the clients should have ruby installed to get the code working, and that won't be possible. Then I thought Java, which might need the java web plugin but that's closer than the other approaches.

I already have got some code, created the applet and embed it to a html to make some tests, but the java console (I suppose that's how it's called) on the browser just won't load.

I'm running icedtea-web on Linux

Here's my Java applet:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class GetClientIP extends Applet {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
            InetAddress thisIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Your local IP address is: " + thisIP.getHostAddress());
       }
      catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

And here's my html test file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
            Java Applet
    </head>

    <body>
            <br><br>This is my page
            <br>Below you see the applet
            <br><br>
            <Applet Code="GetClientIP.class" align=Middle width=300 height=300>
            </Applet>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don't even know if there's a simple approach to show the address to the users, the goal is to show them their local IP address without the need to tweak around their PC's, maybe installing the java plugin won't be acceptable either but, hey, it's something.

Hopefully someone can give me an advice!

Comment: _but the java console (I suppose that's how it's called) on the browser just won't load_ It doesn't have to. If you want the java console to show up, you need to go to your system preferences, choose the "Java" item and select "Always show console"

Comment: When I open the .html file it shows a gray box with the given dimensions (width, height) but won't display a thing. And, of course, running the java programn on terminal gives the expected output

Comment: That's because `System.out.println` prints to the **console**, a java applet is not a console. You have to enable the console if you want to see the output. Another way to do it is to [make a simple GUI that shows some text in the applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need java for this. Just plain javascript.

```
var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})

/*Usage example */
findIP.then(ip => document.write('your local ip address is: ', ip)).catch(e =>   console.error(e));
```